# Click Youtube Subscribe Button Dynamically in Website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, cross-domain, youtube-iframe-api

I have youtube subscribe button in my website. Since the youtube subscribe button style doesn't match my design, I created a button separately. Also, I embedded the youtube subscribe button and kept it hidden.

Now I want to click the hidden button when I click the Subscribe Button I created.

```
$('.cta-subscribe-btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let iframe = $('#___ytsubscribe_0>iframe');

  let button = iframe.contents().find('.yt-uix-button');

  button.trigger("click");
});
```

So far when I tried this code, I receive the following error:

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with
>   origin "http://******.com" from accessing a cross-origin
>   frame.

I checked for the cross-domain access as well.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://******.com')) {
    console.log(event.data);
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Even though this code returns the `event.data` it doesn't allow me to click the button which is inside the iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't work on an iframe in other domain, there is a better way to achieve what you want, check the youtube subscription api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions

Comment: Is there any plugin I can use in the website. I am working on Wordpress Platform

Comment: Sorry I don't know, usually the youtube api plugins is focalized to get data from the account not to customize the buttons, but I think that the worst part is to generate the api credentials, and you need to have this part also if you use a plugin, I suggest you to develop manually your button.